# Databinding against an INotifyCollectionChanged type

Tags: wpf, mvvm, inotifycollectionchanged

I want to have a domain model collection class and a view model class which just reflects and projects the elements of the domain model - but is itself read-only.

My thought here is that both types implement the INotifyCollectionChanged interface and the view model type then just acts as a proxy and projector which wrapes the model elements in an element view model type.

The question is: is implementing INotifyCollectionChanged sufficient to enable WPF databinding to e.g. a DataGrid or ListView or what is the minimal set of interfaces needed to enable collection-based databinding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`INotifyCollectionChanged` won't update your UI if Properties within the elements in your collection change, only if whole elements are added or removed from your collection.

So if you are happy to just track whole element changes, then `INotifyCollectionChanged` will suffice, any further granularity, and you'll need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` within your property setters.

Another point worth noting, is that if you use an `ObservableCollection` to house your list, this already implements `INotifiyCollectionChanged` for you.

**Edit:**

The following is Microsoft's take;

> You can enumerate over any collection that implements the `IEnumerable`
>   interface. However, to set up dynamic bindings so that insertions or
>   deletions in the collection update the UI automatically, the
>   collection must implement the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface. This
>   interface exposes an event that should be raised whenever the
>   underlying collection changes.
>
> WPF provides the `ObservableCollection(Of T)` class, which is a built-in
>   implementation of a data collection that exposes the
>   `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface.
>
> Note that to fully support
>   transferring data values from source objects to targets, each object
>   in your collection that supports bindable properties must also
>   implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.
>
> Before implementing your own collection,
>   consider using `ObservableCollection(Of T)` or one of the existing
>   collection classes, such as `List(Of T)`, `Collection(Of T)`, and
>   `BindingList(Of T)`, among many others. If you have an advanced scenario
>   and want to implement your own collection, consider using `IList`, which
>   provides a non-generic collection of objects that can be individually
>   accessed by index and thus the best performance.

From..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#binding_to_collections

Comment: Interesting. The element view models are (so far) immutable anyway. I could not see the view model displayed in the view - but then I implemented IEnumerable and that did the trick. The main point of implementing a minimal set of interfaces was just to ensure a read-only mode. The number of elements will be very low (< 100), so performance will not be an issue.